# Oracle Apex Counter to display new rows

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page where the users will be adding items to their list. In here, they have an 'add row' button which - just like the name - it adds a new row for the user to include another item.
In order to make a new row visible I have:

- A display only item (which will become hidden later on) that gets increased by one when the user clicks on the 'add row' button (counter original value when the user first enter the page = 1)
- Rows with a server side condition (row 2 will be shown if the counter is greater than 1...row 2 will be shown if the counter is greater than 3 and so on)

Sometimes it works perfectly....most of the times it doesn't.

Pic 1:
Counter now equals 2 (I clicked the add row button once which converted it from 1 to 2) and in theory row number 2 should be displayed now...but it isn't. Only the first one it's being shown:
[image]

Second row server side condition is:
:ROW_COUNTER > 1

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Table structure, sample data? Also, are you using a sequence or identity column for your `ROW_COUNTER` in the database? Because those can and will skip values.

Comment: Not enough info to reproduce. How are rows added - page submit ? Dynamic Action ? Are you able to create a reproducible case on apex.oracle.com to review ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im just gonna guess here and say that it shouldnt be working because you use server side condition for a dynamic change.

Server side conditions only trigger on page initialization and not when you change something dynamically by pressing a button. This should mean that your conditions wont be met until you either refresh or submit the page, depending on your ROW_COUNTER session settings.

--> https://www.foxinfotech.in/2020/02/oracle-apex-using-server-side-conditions.html

Try working with a Dynamic Action. You can execute PLSQL code there too.